# Displaying Image from local android sd card to WebView

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview, android-webview

I'm wondering if there's any way to display local image from Android sd card to WebView?

I've checked this [site](https://androidforums.com/threads/how-to-display-an-image-from-the-sdcard-in-webview.121522/) and SO similar questions, but they all say that you can use [loadDataWithBaseUrl](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html). But all of them doesn't meet my expectation, for example:

```
String html = new String();
    html = ("<html><body><header><h1>Title</h1></header><section><img src=\""+URI_PREFIX+IMAGE_FILENAME+"\" align=left><p>Content</p></section></body></html>" );

    web.loadDataWithBaseURL(URI_PREFIX,
    html,
    "text/html",
    "utf-8",
    "");
```

It creates an html from Java (Android) which I don't want it to be like that. I want it to just load URL (e.g. **http://example.com**) and **pass the local image from Android sd card** to **http://example.com**. I want it this way, because the URL will be changed overtime and there's no way If I have to change my Android App every time I need to change the html.

The **Use Case** is:
In webview / website, I will call an Android's function to open a Camera and take a photo (Works good until here). And here's come the problem, the picture is saved to Android local sd card and I need to display the image on the webview / website and I haven't found any answer to this use case till now.

Need your help, thanks

Comment: `src=\""+URI_PREFIX+IMAGE_FILENAME+"\"` ??? Should we know what you are trying to do? `Please explain your code – Billa`.

Comment: I missed the URI_PREFIX variable, assume that variable is the path (file:///data/data/<package_name>/) to the local storage in android. It will display image from Android local storage to webview

Answer (score 0):

1.Follow the below code.

```
WebView mWebView;
mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
mWebView.getSettings().setAllowFileAccess(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

String base =Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath().toString();
String imagePath = "file://"+ base + "/test.jpg";
String html = "<html><head></head><body><img src=\""+ imagePath + "\"></body></html>";
mWebView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html","utf-8", "");
```

Comment: getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() get the system parth where SD Card is located.Combining base and system parth we can get image path where image is located.

Comment: what's the difference between your solution and my posted code than?